# Get Custom File Version Info from a Native binary using C#

Tags: c#, c++, version

I've got a bunch of native (C++) binaries that I want to scan and retrieve version information about from a C# console application.  Using `System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo` I am able to get the actual version strings, company name, etc.  However there is a `"Build Date"` string in there (which is shown by the Windows File Properties `"Version"` tab), and it is not being retrieved by `FileVersionInfo`.

It seems that `"Build Date"` is technically custom data placed in the file, which I guess would be why I `FileVersionInfo` does not automatically grab this data, but is there any way to get these custom values?

In the native binaries, the `"Build Date"` string is included via an .RC file, using the following section:

```
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904e4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "Build Date", "11/03/2009"
            VALUE "CompanyName", "My Company "
            VALUE "FileDescription", "My DLL"
            VALUE "FileVersion", VERSTR
            VALUE "InternalName", "MyCode.dll"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright © Me"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", VERSTR
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252
    END
END
```

I am then trying to retrieve the information in C# like this:

```
FileVersionInfo ver = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path);
Console.WriteLine(ver.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If the FileVersionInfo class doesn't do want you want, you can always turn to [the native version info APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646981(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Ok, and I could definitely PInvoke into these APIs, but is there absolutely no .NET API that would let me do this?

Comment: Don't think so. If there was, the FileVersionInfo class surely would be it.